# Как сделать так чтобы найти что то похожее с переменной

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType

session = vk_api.VkApi(token='')


def send_message(user_id, message):
    session.method("messages.send", {
        "user_id": user_id,
        "message": message,
        "random_id": 0
        })

for event in VkLongPoll(session).listen():
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.to_me:
        text = event.text.lower()
        user_id = event.user_id

        if text == "":
            
            send_message(user_id, "Сырье 50кк")
            print(user_id)
```

У меня не получается сделать так чтобы код видел сообщение от бота:

" склад твоего бизнеса пуст. тебе следует заказать сырьё.

ты можешь настроить, какие уведомления будут приходить тебе, в настройках."

беда в том что я незнаю как записать в строку if text == "" это сообщение ведь сообщение с переходом в 2 строку

Comment: Перевод строки можно записать как `\n`. Но вообще это выглядит неправильным, затачиваться на конкретную длинную такую строку.

Comment: это я пробовал, но мне нужно записать в сравнение переменной чтобы она видела этот переход строки

Comment: Ну вот и записывайте `if text == 'строка1\nстрока2':`

Comment: @АлександрКудымов а нужен ли реально перенос? Можешь убрать его, заменив пробелом